# Required Whitespace missing while validating DTD/XML

Tags: xml, dtd

I am using w3 schools validation tool to validate my xml file with my dtd. Here is what I have, but I get required whitespace missing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE COUNTRYINFO
[
<!ELEMENT COUNTRY(NAME, POPULATION, AREA)>
<!ELEMENT NAME(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT POPULATION(#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT AREA(#PCDATA)>
]> 
<COUNTRYINFO>
 <COUNTRY>
  <NAME>UNITED STATES</NAME>
  <POPULATION>314867000</POPULATION>
  <AREA>3794101</AREA>
 </COUNTRY>
</COUNTRYINFO>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. There needs to be a space after `<!ELEMENT COUNTRY` before the left parenthesis (applies to all the other `<!ELEMENT...` tags as well.
2. The `<COUNTRYINFO>` element needs to be declared

Corrected DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE COUNTRYINFO
[
<!ELEMENT COUNTRYINFO (COUNTRY)>
<!ELEMENT COUNTRY (NAME, POPULATION, AREA)>
<!ELEMENT NAME (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT POPULATION (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT AREA (#PCDATA)>
]>
```